# About James R. Munkres "Analysis on Manifolds" p.91 Theorem 11.1(b)

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, measure-theory

> **Definition.**
>   Let $A$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.
>   We say $A$ has measure zero in $\mathbb{R}^n$ if for very $\epsilon > 0$, there is a covering $Q_1, Q_2, \dotsc$ of $A$ by countably many reactangles such that
>   $$
>   \sum_{i=0}^\infty v(Q_i) < \epsilon\,.
> $$
>   (b)
>   Let $A$ be the union of the countable collection of sets $A_1, A_2, \dotsc$
>   If each $A_i$ has measure zero in $\mathbb{R}^n$, so does $A$.
>
> *Proof.*
>   To prove (b), cover the set $A_j$ by countably many reactangles
>   $$
>   Q_{1j}, Q_{2j}, Q_{3j}, \dotsc
> $$
>   of total volume less than $\epsilon/2^j$.
>   Do this for each $j$.
>   Then the collection of rectangles $\{Q_{ij}\}$ is countable, it covers $A$, and it has total volume less than
>   $$
>     \sum_{j=1}^\infty \epsilon/2^j
>   = \epsilon.
> $$
>
> (Original scanned image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUpnB.png).)

I am reading James R. Munkres "Analysis on Manifolds" now.

I think there is a **logical gap** in the proof of Theorem 11.1(b)(p.91).

He showed the following inequality:
$$
    \sum_{j = 1}^{\infty} \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} v(Q_{ij})
  < \sum_{j = 1}^{\infty} \frac{\epsilon}{2^j}
  = \epsilon
$$
But I think it was necessary for him to show the following equality:
$$
      v(Q_{11})
    + v(Q_{21}) + v(Q_{12})
    + v(Q_{31}) + v(Q_{22}) + v(Q_{13})
    + \dotsb
  = \sum_{j = 1}^{\infty} \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} v(Q_{ij})
$$

Am I wrong or not?

If I am right, then please show the above equality.

Comment: It's hard to say whether you are right or not. It is well known that every infinite series of nonnegative terms can be rearranged at will without affecting the limiting value. I think Munkres simply assumed that his readers would know this fact.

Comment: Related: [Rearranging a series of nonnegative terms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/503774/rearranging-a-series-of-nonnegative-terms).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No logical gap here. Pay attention to his first sentence:

> Cover the set $A_j$ by countably many rectangles **of total volume** less than $\varepsilon /2^j$.

---

Sorry, the statement above may not be on topic. Try search theory about "Double series". You may also prove that the double series is bounded by $\varepsilon$ by truncating the series and take the limit.